# Why is my flyout crashing when I try to create a StackPanel with two child elements and assign that to a Flyout?

Tags: c#, dynamic, winrt-xaml, application-settings, callisto

I'm trying to invoke a Callisto Flyout when right-tapping on a grid in a GridView (the ultimate goal is to allow the user to change a value and store that in an ApplicationDataContainer). I first tried it with a sample that creates a menu that I found online -- that works, but I don't want a menu.So I tried changing it up from a menu to a StackPanel with a TextBlock and a TextBox on it. This code, though:

```
private void ItemView_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var flyOut = new Flyout {PlacementTarget = sender as UIElement, Placement = PlacementMode.Mouse};

    var sp = new StackPanel {MinWidth = 240, MinHeight = 80, Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal};

    var tblk = new TextBlock {MinWidth = 60, MinHeight = 72};
    sp.Children.Add(tblk);

    TextBox tb = new TextBox {MinWidth = 120, MinHeight = 72};
    sp.Children.Add(tb);

    flyOut.Content = sp;
    flyOut.IsOpen = true;

    UpdateLayout();        
}
```

...crashes and takes me to this line in App.g.i.cs:

```
if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

BTW, I may eventually move this code from the RightTapped event to be in its presumably "proper" place in the Charms Settings, but I reckon this problem needs to be solved in either case.

### UPDATE

I tried to go a different route with this by moving the flyout from "in place" to the Windows 8 Settings panel:

```
public ItemsPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += OnSettingsPaneCommandRequested;
}

private void ItemView_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SettingsPane.Show();
}

private void OnSettingsPaneCommandRequested(SettingsPane sender, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(new SettingsCommand("commandSetSection1Name",
                                                            "Change the name of Section 1", SetAndSaveSectionNames));
    args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(new SettingsCommand("commandSetSection2Name",
                                                            "Change the name of Section 2", SetAndSaveSectionNames));
    args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(new SettingsCommand("commandSetSection3Name",
                                                            "Change the name of Section 3", SetAndSaveSectionNames));
    args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(new SettingsCommand("commandSetSection4Name",
                                                            "Change the name of Section 4", SetAndSaveSectionNames));
    args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(new SettingsCommand("commandSetSection5Name",
                                                            "Change the name of Section 5", SetAndSaveSectionNames));
    args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(new SettingsCommand("commandSetSection6Name",
                                                            "Change the name of Section 6", SetAndSaveSectionNames));
}

private void SetAndSaveSectionNames(IUICommand command)
{
    var flyOut = new Flyout(); // flyOut is a Callisto control

    var sp = new StackPanel {MinWidth = 240, MinHeight = 80, Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal};

    var tblk = new TextBlock {MinWidth = 60, MinHeight = 72};
    sp.Children.Add(tblk);
    TextBox tb = new TextBox {MinWidth = 120, MinHeight = 72};
    sp.Children.Add(tb);
    flyOut.Content = sp;
    flyOut.IsOpen = true;

    UpdateLayout();        
}
```

However, the same thing happens - I can get to the call to SetAndSaveSectionNames() just fine by right-clicking one of the grids in my GridView (ItemView_RightTapped), and then selecting one of

the "Change the name of Section N" TextBlocks or whatever they are on the Settings panel, but then: crasho!

If a fella wants to have dozens of settings in the Settings panel, how will that work - it seems there's not room for much more than the six I added - will it sprout a ViewBox or ScrollBox or something at some point to accommodate this?

Comment: could you try to attach a debugger and see what is the exception being thrown? perhaps you should trace through `ItemView_RightTapped` method.

Comment: Stepping over each line seems to work fine; it just crashes once the event returns, it seems. Commenting out UpdateLayout() makes no difference. I do not have to have flyout declared in my XAML too, do I?

Comment: What is the text of the exception?

Comment: There is no text; the debugger says the exception is not in my code. I still think it's my fault, though (the compiler is probably not broken or whatever the saying is).

Comment: PlacementMode.Mouse is not supported/implemented in my Callisto Flyout control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is probably **NotImplementedException** because the Callisto code has not implemented the **PlacementMode.Mouse** option. I had this issue today.

See: https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/blob/master/src/Callisto/Controls/Flyout/Flyout.cs

```
case PlacementMode.Mouse:
    throw new NotImplementedException("Mouse PlacementMode is not implemented.");
```